# Generate car licence plates

Tags: bash, text-processing

The format is: `AAA-111`

Where `AAA` could be `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]` and `111` can be `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`

**Question**: How can we write a bash script to generate all the possible variations?

Comment: Have you tried using loops?

Comment: **We**? What have **you** tried? Have **you** researched this at all? Let me point you to [how do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) The first point being **Search, and research**

Comment: Does the format allow for leading zeros? For e.g. Finnish plates, maybe postprocess with ... `| sed 's/-0*/-/'` to drop the leading zeros. (Swedish and I believe Estonian plates have them, but use a space instead of a dash.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid using a lot of memory, use nested loops.

```
for az1 in {A..Z}; do
    for az2 in {A..Z} _; do
        for az3 in {A..Z} _; do
            for d1 in {0..9}; do
                for d2 in {0..9}; do
                    printf "$az1$az2$az3-$d1$d2%i\n" {0..9}
                done
            done
        done
    done
done | sed 's/_*-0*/-/'
```

I added underscores to support optional shorter strings, and remove leading zeros, so you can get results like `A-1` and `AB-12` as well as the full `ABC-123` format. (Check the edit history to see how to undo this.)

Comment: all ideas are great, but you win because of customizability :)

Answer (score 3):

As chaos points out, you can use brace expansion for this. Don't forget the `-` in the middle to make them valid according to your format, though:

```
echo {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}-{000..999}
```

If you want a single entry per line you could wrap it inside a `for` loop for instance:

```
for i in {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}-{000..999}
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

You can write them all into a file by adding `> /path/to/file` after the `done`.

If you don't want to use the `for` loop, you can also use [`tr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) to make it print one entry per line:

```
echo {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}-{000..999} | tr " " "\n"
```

Another option would be to use `printf` to print it as a list. This saves you a `tr`.

```
printf '%s\n' {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}-{000..999}
```

Comment: Or save it to a file by just redirecting after the 'done' -- `for i ... done > /path/to/file`

Comment: Use `printf '%s\n' {A..Z} ...` to get rid of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, updated the answer to be more complete/correct.

Answer (score 2):

With bash, you can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
echo {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}-{000..999}
```

But, **attention**. This command will generate a list of `26^3*1000` (17,5 mio) entries.

Comment: Is there an easy modification to generate a random plate instead of all possible?

Comment: Pipe to `sort -R` (this isn't entirely portable) to get a randomized reordering of a list of unique lines. (Completely randomly generated plates would have duplicates.)

Answer (score 0):

While in general you could use brace expansion to create lists like this, this might be big enough to cause problems. Even though it's only ~17 M words, Bash 4.4 doesn't succeed in building the list on a VM with 2 GB of memory, but crashes after 1.5 minutes, without producing any output.

Perhaps something like Perl would be better:

```
perl -le 'foreach $i ("AAA".."ZZZ") { foreach $j ("000".."999") { print "$i-$j" }} ; ' > plates
```

It generates the list in about 5 seconds.

If you have to do it in Bash, split the job to smaller loops.

Though, I do wonder if there would be a better way to do what you're actually trying to achieve. If the data you have doesn't include all 17 million possible plates, you probably don't need to store them all. If it does, you might want to use something other than the shell (i.e. a database).